# XML comments - refer to property in class

Tags: c#, xml-comments

How describe in XML comments that property Encoding is intiliaze to default.

```
public class Settings
{
    public Encoding Encoding{get;set;}

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new instance of a <c>HttpRequestSettings</c> type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        ///     <para>
        ///         How refer to property Encoding in class and describe that property Encoding is set do default ????
        ///     </para>
        /// </remarks>
        public Settings()
        {
            Encoding = Encoding.Default;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
/// ...
/// This constructor sets <see cref="Encoding"/> to its default value.
/// ...
```

Does it lead to any problems? I believe the member (property) should have higher "priority" than the type (class) which is not nested in the current class.